# Modal backdrop doesn't cover relative position elements

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, bootstrap-4

My html has elements Which have relative position. Modal backdrop doesn't cover them. How can I fix it but not reset their position?

[image]

Comment: Looks like a z-index problem. Please add a working code example.

Comment: Hey, we need a bit of your code in order to make it reproducable. But at first it looks like you need to fix the `z-index`'s

Comment: z-index will solve this issue